# Estrutura de banco de dados SQL de uma livraria

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, join

Preciso escrever e povoar um banco de dados MySQL relativo ao controle de uma livraria. Isto envolve: 
3 tabelas:    | editora | livro | autor |

A tabela 'editora' deve ter: id, nome, cidade, estado, país.

A tabela 'livro' deve ter: ISBN, nome, ano.

A tabela 'autor' deve ter: cpf, data de nascimento, 1º nome, 2º nome, país.

Para a criação do banco de dados e de cada tabela não estou tendo problemas. O problema é que preciso organizar estas tabelas de forma que se correlacionem, por exemplo, quando eu quiser deletar todos os registros de livros de um único autor (o que envolveria duas tabelas diferentes para um único comando).

Li sobre o assunto e acho que trata-se do assunto "joins", mas não sei nem por onde começar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie a tabela `editora` depois a tabela `autor`, quando for criar a tabela `livro` faça o relacionamento entre elas. EX:

```
create table editora
(
   id integer(11) primary key NOT NULL,
   nome varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   endereco varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

create table autor 
(
  id integer(11) primary key NOT NULL,
  nome varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  idade integer(3) NOT NULL
);

create table livro 
(
  id integer(11) primary key NOT NULL,
  fk_autor integer(11) NOT NULL,
  fk_editora integer(11) NULL,
  titulo varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  valor float NOT NULL,
  foreign key(fk_autor) references autor(id),
  foreign key(fk_editora) references editora(id)
);
```